# Cmake QT5 linking error

Tags: c++, cmake, qt5

Seems to me that QT5 libraries were not linked correctly when linking them with cmake.
I have a cmake file that set an option to use QT4 or QT5:

```
if(USE_Qt5)

    if(NOT Qt5_PREFIX_PATH)
        set(Qt5_PREFIX_PATH /Applications/Qt/5.2.1/clang_64)
    endif(NOT Qt5_PREFIX_PATH)
    set(WINSDK_LIB_DIR 
        "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.0/Lib/win8/um/x64" 
        "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.0A/Lib"
    )
    set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${3RDPARTY} ${Qt5_PREFIX_PATH} ${WINSDK_LIB_DIR} ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})
    message(STATUS "Qt5 prefix path set to: ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}")
    find_package(Qt5Widgets)
    find_package(Qt5OpenGL)
endif(USE_Qt5)

if(USE_Qt4)
    file(GLOB QT4ROOTS ${3RDPARTY}/Qt/*/bin)
    find_program(QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE NAMES qmake qmake4 qmake-qt4 PATHS ${QT4ROOTS})
    find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED)
    set(QT_USE_QTOPENGL TRUE)
endif(USE_Qt4)
```

if qt4 is selected no problems, compile and execute.
Compiling Qt5 return quite a lot of errors that seems to me a linking problem:

```
/Applications/Qt/5.2.1/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qsizepolicy.h:52:24: error: variable has incomplete type 'class Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT'
class Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT QSizePolicy
                       ^
/Applications/Qt/5.2.1/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qsizepolicy.h:52:7: note: forward declaration of 'Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT'
class Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT QSizePolicy
      ^
/Applications/Qt/5.2.1/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qsizepolicy.h:52:35: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
class Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT QSizePolicy
                                  ^
                                  ;
/Applications/Qt/5.2.1/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qsizepolicy.h:163:31: error: expected a class or namespace
Q_DECLARE_OPERATORS_FOR_FLAGS(QSizePolicy::ControlTypes)
```

???

here is were i link the libraries:

```
if(USE_Qt4 OR USE_Qt5)
    set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
    set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
    # disable autolinking to qmain
    cmake_policy(SET CMP0020 OLD)
    set(USE_QT true)
    add_definitions(-DWITH_QT)
endif(USE_Qt4 OR USE_Qt5)

if(USE_Qt5)
#target_link_libraries(myProject
 #   Qt5::Widgets
#)
    qt5_use_modules(myProject Widgets)
endif(USE_Qt5)
```

Comment: These are very clearly compiler errors - linkers don't know anything about keywords, variables or types, only about symbols. You're missing a definition of the macro `Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT`.

Comment: Can you show the part of your CMakeList where you're using Qt5? Ideally an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) of CMake code.

Comment: Which CMake version? A sufficiently new version will apply "usage requirements" to bring in defines and the like automatically, but with older versions you'll need to put them in manually somehow.